# Crystal Reports one to many result filtering

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have tables A and B left outer joined:

```
Table A
Num JobNumber
Job1 A65486
Job2 A64563
Job3 A64777

Table B
JobNumber Technician
A65486 101
A65486 102
A64563 101
A64563 103
A64777 101
```

I'm trying to return the job numbers that are ONLY assigned to Technician 101.  Ideally it should only return job number A64777, however since 101 was also assigned to A65486 and A64563, it's returning all three.

How do I only return the job number where 101 was the only technician assigned?

Comment: I believe this is more of an SQL issue rather than CR.  The results you are getting are correct if it is just a simple left join as tech. 101 has 3 jobs assigned.

Comment: Maybe @AleksandarZoric is right. But there are some cases that you can do this in Crystal (like filtering a subreport or creating groups criteria). May you add some details about what you want to accomplish? Maybe a snapshot of your RPT design.

Comment: on which field did you left join tables?

Comment: Left outer join tableA.JobNumber > tableB.JobNumber

Comment: When you say ideally it should return A64777.  Why should it? If tech 101 has 2 other jobs assigned? Think of a statement that much be checked so that tech 101 will only return A64777.  At the moment, it will always return all 3 jobs.